# Smooth homeomorphism with Lipschitz inverse is diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to determine if this is true in general and, if not, what is wrong with this proof:

Let $f : A \to B$ for $A, B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function. By definition for each $a \in A$ there is a  linear transformation $F_a : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the error factor defined as $\varphi(a, x) = f(x)-f(a)-F_a(x-a)$ is such that

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|\varphi(a, x)|}{|a - x|} = \lim_{x\to a}\xi(a, x)$$

Where we define $\xi(a, x) = \frac{|\varphi(a, x)|}{|a - x|}$ because it will be convenient later. Also $f$ is bijective with $f^{-1} : B \to A$ Lipschitz continuous. We must show that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at each $b = f(a)\in B$. We define $G_b = [F_{f^{-1}(b)}]^{-1}$. Note that, for arbitrary $y\in B$

$$G_b\circ \varphi(f^{-1}(b), f^{-1}(y)) = G_b(y - b) - [f^{-1}(y) -f^{-1}(b)]$$

Thus $\psi(b, y) = G_b\circ \varphi(f^{-1}(b), f^{-1}(y))$ will play the part of the error factor for $f^{-1}. It remains to show that the following limit evaluates to zero:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to b}\frac{|\psi(b, y)|}{|b-y|} &= \lim_{y\to b}\frac{|G_b\circ \varphi(f^{-1}(b), f^{-1}(y))|}{|b-y|}\\
&\leq ||G_b|| \lim_{y\to b}\frac{|\varphi(f^{-1}(b), f^{-1}(y))|}{|f^{-1}(b) - f^{-1}(y)|}\frac{|f^{-1}(b) - f^{-1}(y)|}{|b-y|}
\end{align*}

Where $||G_b||$ is the matrix norm. The fraction on the right is bounded due to Lipschitz. The one on the left can be rewritten as $\xi(f^{-1}(b), f^{-1}(y))$ and approaches zero due to the continuity of $f^{-1}$ and the hypothesis on $\xi$.

I hope this is coherent and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Hint: Use the inverse mapping theorem.